# How do I remove a file change from a commit that has not been pushed to origin in git?

Tags: git, commit, git-checkout

I have a file that I accidentally added to my most recent commit. I want to remove the changes, but leave the file in the repository. That is because it is a generated sass stylesheet and I always have merge problems with it. Since the server will regenerate it anyway I would really like to just avoid committing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new commit that puts everything in the state you want it to be in, then squash it (via `git rebase -i`) into your most recent commit.

Answer (score 0):

The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-last-git-commit) will likely contain what you need and more for undoing a local commit.

Comment: I found that one before posting this, but it did not work for what I am doing.

Comment: Did you look at more than the accepted answer? There were a lot of alternatives in the high-voted answers.